# Sencha Touch/Ext: How to disable a Form inside a Tab Panel (tabpanel) without disabling the Tab

Tags: forms, extjs, tabs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a simple Tab Panel (tabpanel) where each Tab is a Form. By default, I want the Form to be disabled (read only), and editable once the user taps the Edit button. By setting the "disabled" config of the form, the Tab is also disabled (cannot tap it).

How can I disable the form while keeping the Tab enabled? I have a couple of solutions to fall back on, but I'm hoping for something cleaner/simpler.

My solutions so far:

1. Make the Tabs Containers and place the Form inside the Container
2. Disable at the Fieldset level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My current solution uses the Tab Panel's "initialize" event handler and calls "setDisabled(true)" on each Form Panel.

```
onTabPanelInitializer: function(component, options){
    component.query('formpanel').forEach(function(element, index, array){
        element.setDisabled(true);
    });
}
```

Comment: I would nest it in a container as you've mentioned in your question.